# Load excel file from resources/assembly in C#

Tags: c#, excel, resources, embedded-resource

I need to load an Excel file and write on it. I have already added the file to resources and set its build action to Embedded Resource. My problem is I can't seem to load it from the resources/assembly. I currently have this code:

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string file = string.Format("{0}.UTReportTemplate.xls", asm.GetName().Name);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Stream fileStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(file);

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Unable to create Excel file.");
            return;
        }
        xlApp.Visible = false;
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the file? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are not using the filestream....  You can't Open(file) where file is the embedded resource name...

Comment: How should I go about this? I am new to this, and I currently have no idea on how to proceed.. I tried reading about this in:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292. But I'm having a hard time understanding how..

Comment: save the file stream to a location and then load it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to extract the resource (in this case an excel spreadsheet) from the assembly and write it as a stream to a File, eg:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string file = string.Format("{0}.UTReportTemplate.xls", asm.GetName().Name);
Stream fileStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
SaveStreamToFile(@"c:\Temp\Temp.xls",fileStream);  //<--here is where to save to disk
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\Temp\Temp.xls");
if (xlWorkBook  == null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error: Unable to open Excel file.");
   return;
}
//xlApp.Visible = false;
```

...

```
public void SaveStreamToFile(string fileFullPath, Stream stream)
{
    if (stream.Length == 0) return;

    // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, (int)stream.Length))
    {
        // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
        byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);

        // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
//save resource to disk
string strPathToResource = @"c:\UTReportTemplate.xls";
using (FileStream cFileStream = new FileStream(strPathToResource, FileMode.Create))
 {
            cFileStream.Write(Resources.UTReportTemplate, 0, Resources.UTReportTemplate.Length);
 }

//open workbook
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPathToResource);
if (xlWorkBook  == null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error: Unable to open Excel file.");
   return;
}
xlApp.Visible = false;
```

Comment: saving the file (UTReportTemplate) from resources to disk

Comment: This is the most straight forward answer.  For years I've included the necessary files with the installer.  Now that I'm forced to use OneClick installations the using statement from Sergey can replace my references to the filenames

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add my code snippet here, which works well in Visual Studio 2015. (Just improved [Jeremy Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205252/load-excel-file-from-resources-assembly-in-c-sharp/16205403#16205403).)

(Don't forget to set the Excel file resource's `Build Action` Property to `Embedded Resource` in Property Window.)

```
public void launchExcel()
{
    String resourceName = "Sample.xls";
    String path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);


    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string res = string.Format("{0}.Resources." + resourceName, asm.GetName().Name);
    Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(res);
    try
    {
        using (Stream file = File.Create(path + @"\" + resourceName))
        {
            CopyStream(stream, file);
        }
        Process.Start(path + @"\" + resourceName);
    }catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you with your trouble.

Best regards.