# Copy audio file from Windows Form Application Resource to Hard drive

Tags: vb.net, audio, visual-studio-2013, resources, copy

Using Visual Studio 2013

I have been attempting to copy an audio .wav file from a vb.net Windows Form Application to no avail.  I have attempted a few methods:

```
File.Copy(My.Resource.click1, "c:\destination folder", True)
```

I have tried calling a Sub

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
My.Resources.click1.CopyTo(ms)
Dim ByteArray() As Byte = ms.ToArray
sfr(toPath2 & "\click1.wav", ByteArray)

Public Sub sfr(ByVal FilePath As Byte, ByVal File As Object)
    Dim FByte() As Byte = File
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, FByte, True)
End Sub
```

I have also tried

```
File.WriteAllText(toPath2 & "\click1.wav", My.Resources.click1)
```

How does one copy an audio resource to the hard drive?

Comment: Should be the same principle as this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16205403/495455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.  This is what I came up with to perform the task that I needed.

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
My.Resources.click1.CopyTo(ms)
Dim AudioFile() As Byte = ms.ToArray
File.WriteAllBytes(toPath2 & "\click1.wav", AudioFile) '<-- toPath2 is a specific folder I am saving to
ms.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VB.Net version of the [tested C# version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16205403/495455):

```
Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim file As String = String.Format("{0}.click1.wav", asm.GetName().Name)
Dim fileStream As Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(file)
SaveStreamToFile("c:\Temp\click1.wav", fileStream)  '<--here is the call to save to disk


Public Sub SaveStreamToFile(fileFullPath As String, stream As Stream)
    If stream.Length = 0 Then
        Return
    End If

    ' Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
    Using fileStream As FileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, CInt(stream.Length))
        ' Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
        Dim bytesInStream As Byte() = New Byte(stream.Length - 1) {}
        stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, CInt(bytesInStream.Length))

        ' Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length)
    End Using
End Sub
```

+1 on detailing your attempts before posting, let me know how you go.

Comment: I attempted this solution and came up with this error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code Nice And Easy :

```
Dim FilePath AS String = Application.StartupPath + "\From_Resource.wav"
IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath,My.Resource.click1)
```

and then you can check if it exists :

```
If IO.File.Exists(FilePath) Then MsgBox("File Exists")
```

and one more trick , Play it in Default Player :

```
Process.Start(FilePath)
```