# .NET Embedded resource corrupted content

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, embedded-resource

I've searched all the posts around the web to solve the error i'm getting and don't know what is wrong. Hopefully someone can come up with solution.

I've embededded word template as a resource to my project and i'd like my app to generate it from itself consuming resource. So if i am right, basically, i need to read the stream of embedded resource and write it to temp, then open the temp file, do stuff and finally delete temp file.

This is the code, the problem is when i try to open/read that file, it says it is corrupted but it isn't, i suppose i didnt "copied" the embedded.res the right way to the temp folder. ?

```
Private Sub CreateTemp()

  Dim _assembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly

  Dim tempFolder As String = Path.GetTempPath()
  Dim tempFile As String = temp + "_WordTemplate.dotx"

  Dim strm As Stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("PROJECT.myWordTemplateResource.dotx")

  Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strm, True)
  Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(File.Open(tempfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))

  sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd)

  sr.Close()
  sw.Close()

  Process.Start(tempfile)

End Sub
```

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205252/load-excel-file-from-resources-assembly-in-c-sharp/16205403 - also what's the error message?

Comment: Done! Works like a charm now. I just needed to solve it using filestream class not the streamwriter. Thank you so much Plutonix.

Comment: Huh, @Plutonix only edited the tags.

Comment: StreamWriter is appropriate for text files.  So not a .dotx file, it is a binary file.  You must use FileStream instead.  Having to do battle with the user's installed anti-malware, especially tuned to potentially evil Office templates, would be the other consideration.  Deploying two files is not particularly more difficult to having to deploy one.  If you give it enough time to scan the file (seconds) then you don't have to worry.