# Is it Possible to Recreate an Excel Template in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

The template I am attempting to recreate is this: [Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFxMT.png)

I have started the process of attempting to recreate the template, but I am mainly having issues with cell structure and inserting data into the cells. So I am not sure if I am wasting my time trying to do something that might not be possible.

```
  private void excelcreator()
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            app.Interactive = false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
           
            ws.Range["B7"].EntireRow.Font.Size = 14;
            Range line = (Range)ws.Rows[1];
            line.Insert();
            ws.Range[ws.Cells[7, 2], ws.Cells[7, 4]].Merge();
            app.Cells[7, 2] = "Date";
            app.Interactive = true;
            // AutoSet Cell Widths to Content Size
            ws.Cells.Select();
            ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
            ws.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0;
            ws.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0;
            ws.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0;
            ws.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0;
            ws.Range[7, 2].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
            ws.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
        }
```

I am also getting an error on the line `ws.Range[7, 2].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;` that says: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'"

Comment: Do you have the original file or are you trying to recreate it from the picture? If you have the file you can save it as a template and then just load it and change cell contents.

Comment: I have the file, how would I do this? And it needs to be done within my program (not sure if you were just recommending I change the cells outside of my program).

Comment: Open it in Excel and select Save as > Excel Template.  That will create an .xlst file. When you save it, the file location will change to some templates folder. Be sure to change it to where you want the file saved. Then in your interop code, use `Workbooks.Open(Filename: @"C:\MyTemplate.xltx");` That will open a copy of the template for editing. All you have to do is change cell values or maybe insert rows.

Comment: You don't need Excel to create Excel files. You can use a library like EPPlus or ClosedXML to open an existing file, modify it and save it. Or you can load eg a list of products into a sheet with just `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(products)`

Comment: Er, if you have the file then why not add it to your resources and use it?

Comment: Thank you everyone, I will be taking all of these into consideration. And @SiddharthRout, I did not realize this was possible at the time of me asking the question.

Comment: You may also want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205252/load-excel-file-from-resources-assembly-in-c-sharp) to read from the resource file

Comment: Also if you search google for `add and open excel file resources c#` you will get lot of hits  :) Give it a try and if get stuck post the code you tried and we will take it from there. Also to answer your question on `ws.Range[7, 2].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;` I do not see anything wrong with that line. Also since you know the cell address, you can directly work with the row. `ws.Rows(7).Font.Bold = true;`

Comment: This statement with square brackets works for me `ws.Rows[7].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;`

Comment: I wish I could upvote, I would give you all one, these are all extremely helpful!